# GLFW context change makes EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (java)

Tags: java, java-native-interface, glfw

I'm running two instances of the same application that both have a GLFW window working, then I want one of them to connect to the window of the other instead of drawing on his window.

I'm getting the `windowId` using socket and then i set the context of one application to `0` with `GLFW.glfwMakeContextCurrent(0);` and the context of the latter to the `windowId` of the former with `GLFW.glfwMakeContextCurrent(windowId);` (I also tried to set the second one to `0` but it crashes anyway)

This line `GLFW.glfwMakeContextCurrent(windowId);` makes my code crash, and i get a `hs_err_pid.log` file that looks like this:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffe12cf1cb7, pid=23252, tid=16724
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment Microsoft-32931 (17.0.3+7) (build 17.0.3+7-LTS)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Microsoft-32931 (17.0.3+7-LTS, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [glfw.dll+0x1cb7]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://github.com/microsoft/openjdk/issues
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: [mycommand to run the jar file i won't put it there is sensitive info]

Host: AMD Ryzen 5 5600X 6-Core Processor             , 12 cores, 15G,  Windows 10 , 64 bit Build 19041 (10.0.19041.2913)
Time: Fri May 12 17:07:26 2023 ora legale Europa occidentale elapsed time: 5.485394 seconds (0d 0h 0m 5s)

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00000205f9dab330):  JavaThread "Render thread" [_thread_in_native, id=16724, stack(0x0000004861100000,0x0000004861200000)]

Stack: [0x0000004861100000,0x0000004861200000],  sp=0x00000048611fdfa0,  free space=1015k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [glfw.dll+0x1cb7]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J 8100  org.lwjgl.system.JNI.invokePV(JJ)V (0 bytes) @ 0x0000020587d3cc6c [0x0000020587d3cc20+0x000000000000004c]
j  org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwMakeContextCurrent(J)V+6
j  com.pickytweaks.versionx.loader.screen.multiplayer.XConnectScreen.tick()V+92
...more

siginfo: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005), reading address 0x00000000000002d8


Register to memory mapping:

RIP=0x00007ffe12cf1cb7 glfw.dll
RAX=0x00000205a80d6080 points into unknown readable memory: 0x0000000000000000 | 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
RBX=0x00000000000000d0 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000000000035 is an unknown value
RDX=0x00000205a80d6080 points into unknown readable memory: 0x0000000000000000 | 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
RSP=0x00000048611fdfa0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000205f9dab330
RBP=0x00000048611fe030 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000205f9dab330
RSI=0x0000000000000544 is an unknown value
RDI=0x00000205ab33aae8 is pointing into metadata
R8 =0x00000000000000d0 is an unknown value
R9 =0x00007ffe12cf1c80 glfw.dll
R10=0x00007ffdfe201380 lwjgl.dll
R11=0x0000020587d3cc40 is at entry_point+32 in (nmethod*)0x0000020587d3ca90
R12=0x0 is NULL
R13=0x00000048611fe050 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000205f9dab330
R14=0x00000048611fe020 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000205f9dab330
R15=0x00000205f9dab330 is a thread


Registers:
RAX=0x00000205a80d6080, RBX=0x00000000000000d0, RCX=0x0000000000000035, RDX=0x00000205a80d6080
RSP=0x00000048611fdfa0, RBP=0x00000048611fe030, RSI=0x0000000000000544, RDI=0x00000205ab33aae8
R8 =0x00000000000000d0, R9 =0x00007ffe12cf1c80, R10=0x00007ffdfe201380, R11=0x0000020587d3cc40
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x00000048611fe050, R14=0x00000048611fe020, R15=0x00000205f9dab330
RIP=0x00007ffe12cf1cb7, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00000048611fdfa0)
0x00000048611fdfa0:   000002059b5eea30 0000000000000000
0x00000048611fdfb0:   00000007023b1870 000002059b5ecf78
0x00000048611fdfc0:   00000205ab9d8ea8 0000020587d3cd0c
0x00000048611fdfd0:   00000048611fe040 00000205800094fe
0x00000048611fdfe0:   0000000709fbbea0 0000000000000011
0x00000048611fdff0:   0000000000000000 00000048611fdfe8
0x00000048611fe000:   000002059b5e8b7c 00000048611fe068
0x00000048611fe010:   000002059b5eb138 0000000000000000
0x00000048611fe020:   000000070a1862d8 000002059b5e8c08
0x00000048611fe030:   00000048611fe0b8 00000205800094fe
0x00000048611fe040:   00000048611fe0b8 00000205800094fe
0x00000048611fe050:   00007ffe12cf1c80 0000000000000000
0x00000048611fe060:   00000000000000d0 0000000000000000
0x00000048611fe070:   00000048611fe070 00000205ae867aae
0x00000048611fe080:   00000048611fe0e0 00000205ae86b4f8
0x00000048611fe090:   0000000000000000 000000070a0f6078 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007ffe12cf1cb7)
0x00007ffe12cf1bb7:   06 80 78 ff 20 75 05 f6 01 df 74 15 48 8b d7 48
0x00007ffe12cf1bc7:   8b d9 e8 72 34 01 00 48 85 c0 75 cd e9 5b ff ff
0x00007ffe12cf1bd7:   ff 48 8b 5c 24 30 b8 01 00 00 00 48 8b 74 24 40
0x00007ffe12cf1be7:   48 83 c4 20 5f c3 cc cc cc 48 83 ec 28 83 3d 95
0x00007ffe12cf1bf7:   4d 05 00 00 75 13 33 d2 b9 01 00 01 00 e8 27 02
0x00007ffe12cf1c07:   00 00 33 c0 48 83 c4 28 c3 48 8d 0d 15 66 05 00
0x00007ffe12cf1c17:   48 83 c4 28 e9 20 95 00 00 40 53 48 83 ec 20 83
0x00007ffe12cf1c27:   3d 63 4d 05 00 00 48 8b d9 75 14 33 d2 b9 01 00
0x00007ffe12cf1c37:   01 00 e8 f2 01 00 00 33 c0 48 83 c4 20 5b c3 48
0x00007ffe12cf1c47:   8d 0d df 65 05 00 e8 ee 94 00 00 48 85 c0 75 19
0x00007ffe12cf1c57:   48 8d 15 42 9f 02 00 b9 02 00 01 00 e8 c8 01 00
0x00007ffe12cf1c67:   00 33 c0 48 83 c4 20 5b c3 48 8b cb 48 83 c4 20
0x00007ffe12cf1c77:   5b 48 ff a0 70 02 00 00 cc 40 53 48 83 ec 20 48
0x00007ffe12cf1c87:   8b d9 48 8d 0d 9c 65 05 00 e8 ab 94 00 00 83 3d
0x00007ffe12cf1c97:   f4 4c 05 00 00 48 8b d0 75 11 33 d2 b9 01 00 01
0x00007ffe12cf1ca7:   00 48 83 c4 20 5b e9 7e 01 00 00 48 85 db 74 1f
0x00007ffe12cf1cb7:   83 bb 08 02 00 00 00 75 16 48 8d 15 49 9d 02 00
0x00007ffe12cf1cc7:   b9 0a 00 01 00 48 83 c4 20 5b e9 5a 01 00 00 48
0x00007ffe12cf1cd7:   85 d2 74 1b 48 85 db 74 0e 8b 80 0c 02 00 00 39
0x00007ffe12cf1ce7:   83 0c 02 00 00 74 0d 33 c9 ff 92 50 02 00 00 48
0x00007ffe12cf1cf7:   85 db 74 12 48 8b cb 48 8b 83 50 02 00 00 48 83
0x00007ffe12cf1d07:   c4 20 5b 48 ff e0 48 83 c4 20 5b c3 cc cc cc cc
0x00007ffe12cf1d17:   cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 83 3d 69 4c 05 00 00
0x00007ffe12cf1d27:   75 0c 33 d2 b9 01 00 01 00 e9 fb 00 00 00 83 b9
0x00007ffe12cf1d37:   08 02 00 00 00 75 11 48 8d 15 1b 9d 02 00 b9 0a
0x00007ffe12cf1d47:   00 01 00 e9 e1 00 00 00 48 ff a1 58 02 00 00 cc
0x00007ffe12cf1d57:   cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 40 53 48 83 ec 20 83
0x00007ffe12cf1d67:   3d 23 4c 05 00 00 8b d9 75 11 33 d2 b9 01 00 01
0x00007ffe12cf1d77:   00 48 83 c4 20 5b e9 ae 00 00 00 48 8d 0d a3 64
0x00007ffe12cf1d87:   05 00 e8 b2 93 00 00 48 85 c0 75 16 48 8d 15 16
0x00007ffe12cf1d97:   9d 02 00 b9 02 00 01 00 48 83 c4 20 5b e9 87 00
0x00007ffe12cf1da7:   00 00 8b cb 48 83 c4 20 5b 48 ff a0 60 02 00 00 


Stack slot to memory mapping:
stack at sp + 0 slots: 0x000002059b5eea30 is pointing into metadata
stack at sp + 1 slots: 0x0 is NULL
stack at sp + 2 slots: 0x00000007023b1870 is an oop: java.lang.Class 
{0x00000007023b1870} - klass: 'java/lang/Class'
 - ---- fields (total size 14 words):
 - private volatile transient 'classRedefinedCount' 'I' @12  0
 - private volatile transient 'cachedConstructor' 'Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;' @40  NULL (0)
 - private transient 'name' 'Ljava/lang/String;' @44  NULL (0)
 - private transient 'module' 'Ljava/lang/Module;' @48  a 'java/lang/Module'{0x0000000702002f18} (e04005e3)
 - private final 'classLoader' 'Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;' @52  NULL (0)
 - private transient 'classData' 'Ljava/lang/Object;' @56  NULL (0)
 - private transient 'packageName' 'Ljava/lang/String;' @60  NULL (0)
 - private final 'componentType' 'Ljava/lang/Class;' @64  NULL (0)
 - private volatile transient 'reflectionData' 'Ljava/lang/ref/SoftReference;' @68  NULL (0)
 - private volatile transient 'genericInfo' 'Lsun/reflect/generics/repository/ClassRepository;' @72  NULL (0)
 - private volatile transient 'enumConstants' '[Ljava/lang/Object;' @76  NULL (0)
 - private volatile transient 'enumConstantDirectory' 'Ljava/util/Map;' @80  NULL (0)
 - private volatile transient 'annotationData' 'Ljava/lang/Class$AnnotationData;' @84  NULL (0)
 - private volatile transient 'annotationType' 'Lsun/reflect/annotation/AnnotationType;' @88  NULL (0)
 - transient 'classValueMap' 'Ljava/lang/ClassValue$ClassValueMap;' @92  NULL (0)
 - signature: Ljava/io/OutputStreamWriter;
 - fake entry for mirror: 'java/io/OutputStreamWriter'
 - fake entry for array: NULL
 - fake entry for oop_size: 14
 - fake entry for static_oop_field_count: 0
stack at sp + 3 slots: {method} {0x000002059b5ecf80} 'flushBuffer' '()V' in 'java/io/OutputStreamWriter'
stack at sp + 4 slots: {method} {0x00000205ab9d8eb0} 'invokePV' '(JJ)V' in 'org/lwjgl/system/JNI'
stack at sp + 5 slots: 0x0000020587d3cd0c is at entry_point+236 in (nmethod*)0x0000020587d3ca90
stack at sp + 6 slots: 0x00000048611fe040 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000205f9dab330
stack at sp + 7 slots: 0x00000205800094fe is at code_begin+1118 in an Interpreter codelet
return entry points  [0x00000205800090a0, 0x0000020580009ba0]  2816 bytes
```

Comment: Can we please get a [mcve]?